# Проблема с кнопкой звука в меню паузы в игре на Юнити,как решить?

Tags: c#, unity3d, canvas

помогите пожалуйста реализовать кнопку звук так чтобы при нажатии на неё менялся текст Вкл если нажата и выкл если отжата.Вот условие:Кнопка «Звук» не должна работать, однако она должна сохранять свое значение в PlayerPrefs (возможно, хорошим выбором в этом случае будет использование Int, где 0 – это false, а 1 – это true).
В зависимости от своего состояния кнопка «Звук» должна изменять либо надпись, либо само изображение.
Не могу сладить с Canvas:(
Вот мой недоделанный код:

```
public static int sound;
 public GameObject PauseMenuUI;
 void Start ()
    {
        
        SetText ();
    } 

  void SetText ()
    {
        
        sound = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Выкл", 0);
    
    } 
  void OnGUI ()
    {
        
         GUI.Label (new Rect (50, 130, 200, 30), "Вкл:" + sound);
     GUI.Label (new Rect (40, 100, 150, 20), "Выкл:" + sound);
    }
```

Кто разбирается Канвасе,прошу помочь с кодом для кнопки звука,функцию в Канвасе выставлю сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Добрый день. А зачем вы рисуете GUI.Label, если вы можете создать кнопку, а потом при нажатии на нее из скрипта просто включать/выключать звук в игре и менять надпись вкл./выкл.?

Вы можете просто создать кнопку (объект с компонентом Button), потом в скрипте прописать примерно такой метод:

```
bool isSoundActive;
public void onClick () {
    if (isSoundActive) {
        transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Вкл.";
        // выключаем звук
    }
    else {
        transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = "Выкл.";
        // включаем звук
    
    isSoundActive = !isSoundActive;
}
```

После этого прикрепить скрипт с этой функцией на любой объект, хоть на саму кнопку, потом указать объект со скриптом в компонент Button самой кнопки, выбрать нужный скрипт и функцию.

Ну или вместо этого можно просто вместо компонента Button дать кнопке компонент BoxCollider2D, прицепить ей скрипт, а название метода в скрипте изменить с OnClick на OnMouseDown

Comment: Хорошо,огромное вам спасибо за помощь.